# Cancan Not Preventing Access with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

So I have a product marketplace, and each product belongs to a user (a user can have multiple products). I want the products to be editable and delete-able only by the users who made them. I am using the Devise and CanCan gems, but for some reason everyone can edit/delete everyone else's products.

**product.html.erb**

```
<% if can? :update, Product %>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_product_path(@product) %>
    <% end %>
    <% if can? :destroy, Product %>
    <%= link_to "Delete", product_path(@product), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
<% end %>
```

**ability.rb**

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

    user ||= User.new

        if user.is? :admin
            can :manage, :all
        end
        if user.is? :user
            can :read, :all
            can :create, :all
            can :update, Product do |product|
              product.try(:role) == user || user.role?(:moderator)
            end
            can :destroy, Product do |product|
              product.try(:role) == user || user.role?(:moderator)
        end
    end
  end

end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  has_many :products
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  Roles = [ :admin , :moderator , :user ]

  def is?( requested_role )
    self.role == requested_role.to_s
  end
end
```

I have a ***role*** column in my `users` table, and a ***user_id*** column in my `products` table.
I have a single **admin** user and 3 users with the role **user**. I have also tried making the regular users have the role **NULL** but no change.

Comment: I think this line "can :update, Product do |product|
              product.try(:role) == user || user.role?(:moderator)
            end"    should be product.user == user.  But that is a guess

Comment: I tried replacing the whole line with that, and just erasing the `product.try(:role) == user || user.role?(:moderator) end' and replacing that, but neither worked.